# Dynamically change the variable at each iteration in a for loop?

Tags: python

Given an arbitrary number of people:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.person1 = ["Person_1", 0]
    self.person2 = ["Person_2", 0]
    ...
```

I would like to adjust the value "0" to "25".

How can I change the variable during each iteration so that I don't have to type it as follows:

```
 def daily_income(self):
    self.person1[1] += 25
    self.person2[1] += 25
    ...
```

I tried to adjust the variable name by appending the "i" to the end of the variable name, however, it did not work.

```
def daily_income(self):
    for i in range(1,3):
        'self.person_{}'.format(i)[1] += 25
```

Comment: *appending the "i" to the end of the variable name* You appended "i" to a string.

Comment: Why not use a single dictionary instead of multiple variables ?

Comment: If you just had one big `self.people` structure this problem wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good code design, but it can be done as follows:

```
class People:
    def __init__(self):
        self.person1 = ["Person_1", 1]
        self.person2 = ["Person_1", 2]
        self.person3 = ["Person_1", 3]
        
    def daily_income(self):
        for i in range(1,4):
            attr = 'person{}'.format(i)
            val = getattr(self, attr)
            val[1] += 25
            setattr(self, attr, val)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the variable, either follow this:

```
def daily_income(self):
    for i in range(1,26):
        attr = f'person{i}'
```

or this: (as followed by [bb1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15187728/bb1))

```
def daily_income(self):
    for i in range(1,26):
        attr = 'person{}'.format(i)
        val = getattr(self, attr)
        val[1] += 25
        setattr(self, attr, val)
```